# A type of first order nonlinear ODE : Is there any standard reference for this type of equations?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

How to solve this differential equation for $y$ as a function of $x$?

$f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given any bounded continuous function, the differential equation is given as

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = a(y^2-\frac{f(x)}{b})$$

This is a first order nonlinear ODE. Is there any standard method or reference for this type of ODE?

Comment: It's Riccati's differential equation

Comment: You can combine $b$ with $f$, you can eliminate $a$ by a change in the time scale, so you really have $y'(x)=y(x)^2-f(x)$. Now this is a Riccati equation and related to $u''(x)-f(x)u(x)=0$ which probably has more classified types for simple choices of $f$.